# BIRT report viewer exception

Tags: java, eclipse, cluster-computing, birt

After a recent server failure and new cluster setup the web app for a BIRT report stopped working. I found that the Tomcat server it was stored on was offline so I started the service and now I get the following error message when trying to view the report:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
There is an error in get connection, Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1215)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1179)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:99)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:258)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:252)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:85)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1307)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
There is an error in get connection, Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:580)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:74)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:265)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1875)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
... 59 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
There is an error in get connection, Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:177)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:208)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:405)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:315)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:448)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:145)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:560)
... 64 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:262)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:212)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:234)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java:160)
   at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:239)
   at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
... 74 more
```

Everything was working fine before the server failure but now I'm guessing the problem is with the JDBC listener. Does anyone know how to get it running again? There was an OS cluster and a database cluster but it was set up on the database server.

Thanks

Comment: where was cluster environment set up? birt server or database server?

Comment: I wrote answer for your question. However there is chance that old listener setup is valid, but you need to provide more details regarding DB type/version/environment for answers in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set new JDBC connection parameters for your report data sources, since DB host migrated/switched to clustered environment. Old connection parameters are probably pointing to old environment setup. Check out port connectivity to database using telnet.

Comment: I copied the JDBC URL from the maximo.properties file on the server and replaced the RPT file with the new one. Now when I try to run the report it's stuck on "Processing, please wait.."
It's been like this for 20 mins